# Hyperlink is not working on IE9 from gmail

Tags: php, internet-explorer-9

I have developed a mail body in PHP with a hyperlink 
http://waterhouseresearch.com/pdf/water_1815.pdf

When I hit it in IE9 it is opening fine but when I clicked it from gmail mail body it is loading some time and blank page remaining.
But from other browser like firefox when it is opening from gmail it is finely opening.
Please give me some suggestion to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please right click on the PDF link in gmail body at IE 9 Browser then click to "Open in new tab" see the pdf LOAD PERFECTLY.

Comment: If it is possible, but I don't have any solution for now. It is a problem of IE.

Answer (score 0):

php have no business with browse it a server side scripting  languages so the problem may be in internet explorer

Answer (score -2):

**This is not PHP problem.**

Try this 1

First backup your registry.

Click on Start --> In search bar, type regedt32 and press Enter.

"Registry Editor" will be opened. Go to File --> Export --> Save the registry

backup with any name in your desired location.

Click on the below hyperlink "Fix" and download the file

Fix

Extract it --> If your IE9 is a 32 bit application then select the 32 bit (32on64) File

or else select the 64bit(64on64) File. The above fix works for IE9 also.

After applying the fix, reset the internet explorer settings.

Right-click on the "Internet Explorer" icon --> Properties --> Click on "Advanced"

tab --> Click on "Reset" button.

Good Luck

Comment: @NullPointer : as per I know this is IE9 problem

Comment: In that case, advice to give a notice if its IE9.